# Java method/function to return second shortest string from a list of strings

Tags: java, oop, list, collections

I wanted help regarding  Java program to find out second shortest string from a list of strings.

Can I please have suggestions about:

- How to start?
- How to use iterator for this?
- What is efficient way of solving this?

Comment: What happens if two strings have the same length?

Comment: *"can i plz have suggestions abt how to start.."*  1st get a spell checker, then spell like an adult.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Collections.sort](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) with a comparator that compares two strings based on their length.  Afterwards, you can take the second element from the sorted collection.

**Note**:  This is not the most efficient approach, but as long as performance is not an issue, I'd suggest to use the simplest thing that could possibly work.

In case strings of equal length should be taken into account (i.e. the second shortest string out of `["a", "b", "cc"]` would be `"cc"`), then you could create a hashmap with the length of the strings as a key and a list of strings of that length as their value and taking the second smallest key's value.

Comment: Great answer because A) it really is the best way to do it and B) it won't help sandy on whatever test she is trying to get us to do for her.

Comment: Just to mention this is the easiest but not the most efficient. It is `O(NlogN)` but the task can be done in `O(N)`.

Comment: Also maybe the task is if you have `a`, `b`, `cc` then you should take `cc` as second shortest. Then just taking the second one is not sufficient. You still have to loop over.

Comment: @Petar Minchev That's correct, but since there is no specific need to do it in the most efficient way, I prefer the easier approach rather than a faster one.  I'll mention it in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Maintain two variables the length of the shortest and the length of the second shortest string. So let them be `first` and `second`.

```
first = len(list[0]), second = len(list[0]);

for every other element cur do:
   curLen = len(cur);
   if (curLen < first):
      second = first;
      first = curLen;
   else
   if (curLen < second && curLen > first):
      second = cur;
```

I assume here that you want the second shortest string to have a different length that the shortest string. If you don't want that remove the `&& curLen > first`.

You can maintain along another two variables for the actual strings or just keep what are their indexes in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through list and maintain top two length along with index.

For Example :

```
ab
abc
abcd
a
abcdef
xyz
```

iterate through and have top length = 6 and position = 4, also second top length = 4, position  = 3

Answer (score 0):

Rough idea:

1. Use a for loop to iterate through the collection
2. Use two local variables (`String actualShortestString, actualSecondShortestString`, defined outside of the loop) to store the shortest and second shortest string
3. `Math.min(actualString.length(), actualShortestString.length())` **will** help.
4. the *second shortest* String is the *previous* shortest String

---

*Note* - you're asked to implement a *Select* algorithm to find the *kth smallest element*. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_kth_element#Selecting_k_smallest_or_largest_elements) has a some background and algorithms for that task.

Answer (score 0):

I would say:

```
String[] loveLetters = {"Roses are red, ...", "I<3U", "I don't have time for a poem."};

String[] shortest = {"",""}; //The shortest and the second shortest.

for (int i=0;i<loveLetters.length;i++) {
  if (shortests[0].equals("") || loveLetters[i].length() < shortest[0].length()) {
    shortest[1] = shortest[0];
    shortest[0] = loveLetters[i];
  }
  else if (shortest[1].equals("") || loveLetters[i].length() < shortest[1].length()) {
    shortest[1] = loveLetters[i];
  }
}
System.out.println("What? The second shortest love letter you wrote me was: " + shortest[1] + "!!?! You should write more!");
```